# How to convert array id to list element from json Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of id in my page

`var index = ['0', '5', '9'];`

from a list of class in **costant.dart**

```
  static final List<SensationItem> sensastionList = [
    SensationItem(
        code: 0,
        title: 'Formicolio / Intorpidimento',
        imageUrl: 'images/intorpidimento.png'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 1,
        title: 'Sudorazione intensa',
        imageUrl: 'images/sudorazione.png'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 2, title: 'Dolore al petto', imageUrl: 'images/petto.png'),
    SensationItem(code: 3, title: 'Nausea', imageUrl: 'images/nausea.png'),
    SensationItem(code: 4, title: 'Tremori', imageUrl: 'images/tremori.png'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 5,
        title: 'Paura di perdere il controllo',
        imageUrl: 'images/controllo.png'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 6,
        title: 'Sbandamento / Vertigini',
        imageUrl: 'images/vertigini.png'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 7, title: 'Palpitazioni', imageUrl: 'images/palpitazioni.png'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 8,
        title: 'Sensazione di soffocamento',
        imageUrl: 'images/soffocamento.png'),
  ];
}
```

How I can convert and find the index element in List

Ex.:

0 => 'Formicolio / Intorpidimento'

4 => 'Tremori'

And I want to add at another list and print it in a widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

I used `sensationList.where` to filter the results that where in your list of indexes (I turned them into integers first so that they could match) and them used `forEach()` to add the results into the new list of `SensationItem` like you asked

You can copy and paste it into DartPad to see how it's working

```
void main() {
  final List<SensationItem> sensastionList = [
    SensationItem(
        code: 0,
        title: 'Formicolio / Intorpidimento',
        imageUrl: 'images/intorpidimento.png'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 1,
        title: 'Sudorazione intensa',
        imageUrl: 'images/sudorazione.png'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 2, title: 'Dolore al petto', imageUrl: 'images/petto.png'),
    SensationItem(code: 3, title: 'Nausea', imageUrl: 'images/nausea.png'),
    SensationItem(code: 4, title: 'Tremori', imageUrl: 'images/tremori.png'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 5,
        title: 'Paura di perdere il controllo',
        imageUrl: 'images/controllo.png'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 6,
        title: 'Sbandamento / Vertigini',
        imageUrl: 'images/vertigini.png'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 7, title: 'Palpitazioni', imageUrl: 'images/palpitazioni.png'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 8,
        title: 'Sensazione di soffocamento',
        imageUrl: 'images/soffocamento.png'),
  ];
  
  var index = [0, 5, 9];
  
  List<SensationItem> newList = [];
  
  sensastionList.where((element) => index.contains(element.code)).forEach((item) => newList.add(item));
  
  print(newList);
   
}

class SensationItem {
  int code;
  String title;
  String imageUrl;

  SensationItem({this.title, this.imageUrl, this.code});
  
  @override
  String toString() => 'Sensation item - code: ${this.code} title: ${this.title}';
  
}
```

Comment: Good! If I want to print a object? Not only a title?

Comment: .map((element) => element.title)); you have access to the element here. I'm only putting the title on the new array but you can do anything with it. element here is the SensationItem object

Comment: `print(sensastionList.where((element) => index.contains(element.code)).map((element) => element));`

Return **(Instance of 'SensationItem', Instance of 'SensationItem', Instance of 'SensationItem')**

Comment: this is the expected behavior when you print an object. you can try to implement a custom toString() method if you want a more meaningful representation of this object when you print it

Comment: like this:   @override
  String toString() => 'Sensation item - code: ${this.code} title: ${this.title}';

Comment: You can show me a practical example? Maybe the result add a list

Comment: you want to add the resulting objects to another list? ill edit my answer